# What should I use for build benchmarking?

Tags: msbuild, build, benchmarking

We are updating our development machines with the specific purpose of optimizing build times.

I'd like to know what people recommend we use to build as a benchmark.  Ideally I'd like something that takes 30 seconds or longer on typcial developer boxes, and something that can be built in Visual Studio 2010 or 2008.

Any recommendations appreciated.  I will vote you up one, regardless of your suggestion.

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to share some details on the setup you end up with? I'm curious to see the results.

Answer (score 1):

DotNetNuke worked well for VB.Net build benchmarking as well.